# Initializing a static std::map<int, unique_ptr<int>> in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, static-initialization

This is a similiar question to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138600/initializing-a-static-stdmapint-int-in-c). The answer that I think has the most promise has to do with templated static initialization. Here is the class from that answer:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class create_map
{
private:
    std::map<T, U> m_map;
public:
    create_map(const T& key, const U& val)
    {
        m_map[key] = val;
    }

    create_map<T, U>& operator()(const T& key, const U& val)
    {
        m_map[key] = val;
        return *this;
    }

    operator std::map<T, U>()
    {
        return m_map;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
std::map mymap = create_map<int, int >(1,2)(3,4)(5,6);
```

This works great for a structure or a class as well as the base types. What I would like to do is to use this with a `unique_prt<Structure\Class>` as the value like this:

```
std::map mymap = create_map<DWORD, std::unique_ptr<Structure|Class>>(1, new Structure|Class())(2, new Structure|Class())
```

I am trying to use a template class so that I can have the value be any type. I got the idea from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702235/c-stdmap-holding-any-type-of-value) to use an interface as a base class and then a template derived class to hold any type of value. So those classes look like this:

```
class MyFieldInterface
{
public:
    int m_Size;
    virtual ~MyFieldInterface() = default;
}

template <typename T>
class MyField : public MyFieldInterface {
    T m_Value; 
}
```

Then the map can be setup like I described earlier:

```
std::map<DWORD, unique_ptr<MyFieldInterface>> mymap;
```

But trying to initialize it with create_map fails:

```
std::map mymap = create_map<DWORD, unique_ptr<MyFieldInterface>>(1, new MyField<DWORD>())(2, new MyField<char>())(3, new MyField<WORD>())
```

The error that I get is this:

```
operator()
Error: no instance of constructor "create_map<T, U>::create_map [with T=DWORD, U=std::unique_ptr<MyFieldInterface, std::default_delete<MyFieldInterface>>]" matches the argument list
argument types are: (DWORD, MyField<DWORD>*)
```

So I thought that I need a constructor and an operator() that can handle the pointer properly. I added both to the class:

```
create_map(const T& key, const U* val)
{
    m_map[key] = val;
}

create_map<T, U>& operator()(const T& key, const U* val)
{
    m_map[key] = val;
    return *this;
}
```

I got the same error. So I tried without the `*`:

```
create_map(const T& key, const U val)
{
    m_map[key] = val;
}

create_map<T, U>& operator()(const T& key, const U val)
{
    m_map[key] = val;
    return *this;
}
```

I got the same error. As I'm writing this, I realized that the problem may be related to the inheritance and not necessarily create_map's operator. **Can you help me figure out the operator() definition or the base/derived class definition that I need to get this to work?**

*Please limit your answers to not include the Boost C++ libraries as I am not allowed to use them here at work.*

**Edit**: updated MyFieldInterface as requested by T.C.

Comment: Don't use multiple naked `new`s in the same full expression. It isn't exception safe. Also `MyFieldInterface` needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: In any event, you'll need to move everything, because `unique_ptr` cannot be copied, which pretty much requires major surgery on `create_map`.

Comment: @T.C. I updated `MyFieldInterface` as you requested. I've also thought about your other comments. I changed to using a `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared`. That resolves the problem nicely. Error has gone away. Once I've had a chance to test it, I'll write it up as the answer. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible implementation:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class create_map
{
private:
    std::map<T, U> m_map;
public:
    create_map(T key, U val)
    {
        m_map.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(val));
    }

    create_map&& operator()(T key, U val) &&
    {
        m_map.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(val));
        return std::move(*this);
    }

    operator std::map<T, U>() &&
    {
        return std::move(m_map);
    }
};
```

Note the taking argument by value and then moving it into the map with `emplace`, and the conversion operator that moves from `m_map`.

I don't know if MSVC 2012 supports ref-qualifiers. If it doesn't, you'll need to remove it (that's the two `&&`s after the function parameter list). The point of that is to enforce that `create_map` should only be used as a temporary. It is possible to also enforce that the conversion operator is only called once, but I didn't do that in the code above.

Now your calls cannot use naked `new`s because 1) it isn't exception-safe and 2) raw pointers cannot be implicitly converted to `unique_ptr`s. A simple `make_unique` implementation that doesn't take arrays into account is

```
namespace util {
    template<class T, class... Args>
    std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
}
```

You can then change the `new MyField<DWORD>()`s to `util::make_unique<MyField<DWORD>>()`<sup>*</sup>.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d651282895557630).

---

<sup>*</sup> Using a qualified call disables ADL, which [can have surprising effects when you upgrade your compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521822/c11-14-make-unique-ambigious-overload-for-stdstring/28521904#28521904) if your call has arguments. A full implementation of `make_unique` according to the spec can be found in the example code in [N3656](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3656.txt), the `make_unique` proposal paper.

Comment: I'm getting "'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair': function does not take 2 arguments" in Visual Studio 2017. I really appreciate any help for compiling this

Answer (score 0):

With some guidance from T.C. and the fact that VC2012 does not have make_unique in it, I changed from using a unique_ptr<> to a shared_ptr<>.

```
std::map mymap = create_map<DWORD, shared_ptr<MyFieldInterface>>(1, make_shared<MyField<DWORD>>())(2, make_shared<MyField<char>>())(3, make_shared<MyField<WORD>>())
```

This gave me the functionality I was looking for without having to change the underlying classes. While this works for my needs, I am actually going to mark T.C.'s answer as correct because it works regardless of which one you use.